# Vector reprojected to the same projection in different GIS are not aligned

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, arcmap, qgis-3

I have a vector file from the land use area around a river in South America. It was mapped originally in Datum SIRGAS2000 and Projection UTM, zone 23S - [EPSG:31983](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/sirgas-2000-utm-zone-23s/).

As the area of study is much beyond a single UTM zone and I need to calculate areas and distances from it, I needed to change to a projection that respected areas and distances. My colleagues and I followed a set of parameters defined for Datum SIRGAS2000 and projection Albers (it does not have an EPSG code). The proj4 code for it is:

`+proj=aea +lat_1=-5 +lat_2=-42 +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=-60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

I reprojected it in QGIS 3 and my colleague did the same in ArcMap 10, both on Windows, but the results were different: her map was aligned with the original UTM one, but mine was displaced to the West. We already repeated the process multiple times, but with no success. Any hints on the reasons and what version of the reprojection we should trust and use?

[image: Green: reprojected in QGIS, Black: reprojected in ArcMap]
Fig: Green: reprojected in QGIS, Black: reprojected in ArcMap.

Comment: May the problem be the GDAL version my QGIS is using?

Comment: Does the SIRGAS2000 definition have a +wgs84 parameter and if so is it all zeroes? What are the well-known text definitions being used from ArcGIS?

Comment: @mkennedy: Does the SIRGAS2000 definition have a +wgs84 parameter and if so is it all zeroes?
I am not sure, I still starting to know the meaning of the proj4 parameters. How can I check if the SIRGAS2000 definition has that?

Comment: "What are the well-known text definitions being used from ArcGIS?" I don't know that, sorry. I am the one who uses linux, so I have no experience in ArcGIS. My colleague uses it, I can ask her today.